# Was there a social stigma for British born/living in India prior to WW2/Indian independence?

Tags: british-empire

My father (1926 - 2007) always said he was  born and raised in England until immigrating to Australia in 1947 after being discharged from the army. I have now found out through his army records that he was born and lived in India until joining the army. Trying to find some understanding for the secret/deception. Both his parents were British.

Yes, he had British citizenship. Getting his birth certificate was how this started. No record of him or his family in Grassmoor, Derbyshire where he said he was brought up. There are records in India. Just confused why this would be kept secret by his whole family who all immigrated to Australia. No family members left to interrogate.

Comment: It would be interesting to know at what point you believe that he experienced this "social stigma" and when he started claiming to have been raised in England. Presumably, he didn't do this while living in India. Did he ever actually live in Britain? Did he have British citizenship?

Comment: Is it possible that he falsified the Army records? Is there any reason why it might have been advantageous to his enlistment (commission) to have been born in India?

Comment: It's certainly possibly your dad is correct and the army records are wrong. You should look for a more reliable source, such as a birth record in the town where he said he was born. Do that before going down this path. You may find that your dad was right all along.

Comment: Not really an answer, but think there was a social stigma against "nabobs", "colonials", "Anglo-Indian"  Read Agatha Christie around the first 3rd of the 20th century - Anglo-Indian colonels are usually depicted as silly old men always talking of "tiffin" etc. Don't see how it would have affected your dad's enlistment /commission in the British Army, though, it was a purely social snobbery, I think.

Comment: It should be relatively easy to obtain your father's birth certificate, whether he was born in England or in India. Do you know the place in England in which he claimed to have been born? Does he have a relatively uncommon surname? Those will be two helpful factors, also if you happen to know his exact date of birth that too will be an advantage. But irrespective of any of that it shouldn't be rocket science digging out the birth certificate of someone born as recently as 1926. .

Comment: @TheHonRose: Didn't Christie refer to **all** retired colonels in a similar derogatory fashion?

Comment: Did Australia have immigration laws in place post-war that made it easier for British-born citizens to enter (compared to say Indian-born)? That could be a reason.

Comment: @SteveBird has nailed it IMO. I don't want to offend David - assuming he's an Aussie - but Australia had a somewhat covert but highly bigoted approach to immigration at that time. His father may well have known that putting down his India background could only lead to confusion and harm to his immigration application. Although many Brits had difficulty adapting to life in Britain after India (due to relative loss of social status and spending power) I am not aware of any prejudice against them. Also I have some genealogy experience and could check David's father details in case of some mix-up.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens No, I don't think so. Colonel Bantry is relatively  "normal", and most of her Chief Constables are retired colonels and not all of the most batty.

Comment: Thanks all. I think the Australian immigration reason offered by Steve Bird and TheMathemagician may be the answer. Why keep up the charade for the next 60 years, who knows? Also puts into question my following of Derby in English football for all these years. haha.

Comment: It sounds more likely you've been given the wrong person's data to be honest.

Comment: @TheHonRose there are two distinct meanings of Anglo-Indian, which confuses things. There would have been substantial racial prejudice against Anglo-Indians (= mixed-race background), but not against Anglo-Indians (= white but born/lived in India); for them, as you say, social snobbery but not much else.

Comment: See Burmese Days by George Orwell for a taste of how my fellow countrymen viewed their contemporaries living in India. They seemed to see them as bores, but nothing worse... Doesn't seem to be a good motive for lying about living there, really.

Comment: @Andrew Yes, to an extent - racially mixed people would have encountered more prejudice than whites, but from the beginning of British presence in India so called "nabobs", who made their fortunes in the subcontinent then returned to UK had trouble *gate crashing* the upper echelons of British society, despite their wealth.

Comment: The army records show his full name, his birthday and names both his parents. Have also found records of his brothers in India. This explains why he would never elaborate when asked about his childhood.

Comment: @David I certainly wouldn't be put off looking into the matter further by that speculative suggestion. For one I do not believe the *White Australia Policy* excluded whites and Anglo-Indians born in Asia. When I lived in Australia in the 1970s I met various people of Anglo-Indian descent.  If you start with a website like [Find My Past](http://www.findmypast.co.uk/) you should have little trouble finding your father's birth records.

Answer (score 4):

MY father was born in Hong Kong (in 1923), and he always made the distinction between a British "citizen" (born in the British Isles), and a British "subject" (born elsewhere in the Empire). It was the difference between being a British "native" or "colonial."